# Show contents as per the selected tabitem in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tabcontrol, tabitem

I have an application named **App Window**. In which i need to display the installed apps in the tab items. Each tab item contains the data about its corresponding application. If a new app installed, then window will create a new tab item for the newly installed app.

*I have done upto creating a new tab item as per the installed applications.

**Code i used:**

```
private List<TabItem> _tabItems; 
private TabItem _tabAdd;

try
{
    _tabItems = new List<TabItem>();

    InstalledApps.DataContext = _tabItems;

    InstalledApps.SelectedIndex = 0;

    if (A Installed)
        this.AddTabItem("A");

    if (B Installed)
        this.AddTabItem("B");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}


private TabItem AddTabItem(string AppName)
{

    int count = 1;

    // create new tab item
    TabItem tab = new TabItem();

    tab.Header = AppName;
    string tabName = AppName.ToLower();
    tab.Name = tabName;
    tab.HeaderTemplate = InstalledApps.FindResource("TabHeader") as DataTemplate;

    TextBox txt = new TextBox();
    txt.IsReadOnly = true;

    tab.Content = txt;

    _tabItems.Insert(count - 1, tab);

    return tab;
}
```

**Xaml:**

```
<TabControl Height="555" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,-27,0,0" Name=" InstalledApps " ItemsSource="{Binding}" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" SelectionChanged=" InstalledApps_SelectionChanged" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="992" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="4">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                        <Grid Name="Panel">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Header" Margin="80,10" />
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="#FFEFEFEF" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="#FFE0E0E0" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="TabHeader" DataType="TabItem">
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem }, Path=Header}" />
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

    </TabControl.Resources>
</TabControl>
```

**My requirement is:**
While i am selecting anyone tab from the listed tab items, then it should show its corresponding contents(logo, app name) in is content part.

Thanks in advance,
Kathiresan S.

Comment: Do you see any item in TabControl when you run your application?

Comment: Yes. My application showing the tab items A and B in the application window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create class representing the data you want to display. e.g:

```
public class AppDetails {
   public Uri Logo { get; set; }
   public string AppName { get; set; }
   //etc
}
```

then set the AppDetails to `TabItem.Content` and define `TabItem.ContentTemlate` similarly as you did with HeaderTemplate.

```
tab.ContentTemplate = InstalledApps.FindResource("TabContent") as DataTemplate;
tab.Content = new AppDetails{ ... };
```

alternatively, you can skip ContentTemplate and assign some FrameworkElement (e.g. custom UserControl) directly to the tab content:

```
tab.Content = new AppDetailsUserControl(AppName, Logo);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ans to *If a new app installed, then window will create a new tab item for the newly installed app.*

1. you should bind the DataContext of TabControl to ObservableCollection so that any new Tabitem added by backend will be shown UI directly.

Ans to *While i am selecting anyone tab from the listed tab items, then it should show its corresponding contents(logo, app name) in is content part*

2. You should set the content `tab.Content` to a UserControl or Model (if Model then define DataTemplate in ResourceDictionary). UserControl or DataTemplate can define what information should be displayed at what control and their visual hierarchy.